What are the possible meanings of “with” in Philippians 1:23
Bible passages seem to use “with” (syn) in terms of accompanying and in terms of a spiritual connection.
In Philippians 1:23, what are the valid options for the meaning of “with” and do other factors influence the meaning?
Philippians 1:21-24


For to me, to live is Christ and to die is gain.
But if I am to live on in the flesh, this will mean fruitful labor
for me; and I do not know what I will choose.
But I am hard-pressed between the two, having the desire to depart and be
with Christ, for that is very much better,
yet to remain on in the flesh is more necessary for your sake.


I think accompany would mean Paul would go to where Jesus is, in Heaven, without waiting for the rapture.  If there is a spiritual connection, Paul could die and stay on Earth, in some undescribed state.
The question is based on whether there are multiple options based on Greek interpretation or if there is only one valid Greek interpretation, and what is it?  It’s not based on a theological position.  I request that the text to tell the answer.  :-)
For some examples of spiritual connections using “syn”:
Romans 6:8; Romans 8:32; 1 Corinthians 5:4; 1 Corinthians 16:4; 2 Corinthians 1:21; 2 Corinthians 4:14; 2 Corinthians 13:4; Colossians 2:5; Colossians 2:13; Colossians 2:20; 1 Thessalonians 5:10
Here is 1 Thessalonians 5:9-10


For God has not appointed us for wrath, but for obtaining salvation through our Lord Jesus Christ,
who died for us, so that whether we are awake or asleep, we will live together with Him.


In 1 Thessalonians 5:10, we are already “with” Christ.  Then, does Paul stating “be with Christ” (Phil 1:23) a redundant statement since believers are with Christ already, or does the Greek indicate they are different types of “with”? (Bonus points for knowing if asleep is a euphemism for death, in this instance).

The usual interpretation is that Paul is undecided as to whether to depart this life, to die and go to be with Christ in paradise ; or to remain on earth, alive, in the flesh, and to continue to minister to his brethren. I don't see either of your interpretations being supported either by the prepositions or by other, numerous, passages of scripture.

@Nigel This scripture is often referenced by those who believe the soul goes to Heaven immediately after death.  Thus, this analysis of “with Christ” or “with Him”.

@Nigel J, Based on the meaning of “with”, we may or may not be able to clarify if believers are already “with Him” before death.  Are some with Him spiritual or do souls go to Heaven and “with” means “in the same place”?

It is clear from scripture (and from experience) that the Son of God is known (and known intimately) during this life, prior to death. He is with his own, in Spirit, undoubtedly. There is also being 'asleep in the Lord' which describes a disembodied state. Then there is resurrection and glory to follow. You would need to ask a series of questions (one step at a time) to research all of this. It cannot be covered, all by one question and multi-questions are not permitted for practical reasons.

Up-voted to encourage patient research. +1.

@Nigel J, I hope that the concentration be on understanding “with”, without a preconceived view, and see where it leads to understanding .  :-)
